# Windows Server 2012 Certificate Stores not updating

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

According to Microsoft, Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8.1 automatically update Digital Certificates.

Microsoft Security Advisory 3050995 https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/3050995  says Server 2012 and Windows 8.1 don't need to do anything as they are automatically protected, however when checking the certificate stores on either there's no updates to the Untrusted Certificates/Certificate Trust List, which per that advisory should have added MCSHOLDING TEST.

This is a 100% Server 2012 Essentials R2 / Windows 8.1 small biz location with no changes to OOB as regards certificates.  Why is this not updating?  Pretty concerning if the certs don't get updated automatically as MS claims they do.